# How to open a remote samba shared folder? (from ubuntu to ubuntu)

Tags: networking, samba

I am sharing a folder on my ubuntu 20.04 machine using samba. I access the folder from my windows 10 machine. Now, I want to access the folder from my ubuntu 18.04 notebook. I searched the net but couldn't find how to access the samba folder from ubunt machine.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyAGYpx-vn0&t=53s this did't help). When I start samba://myipaddr, it doens't open the folder. and my file manager doesn't show the remote folder open menu.

Comment: I see 'Computer' on 'On This Computer' and 'Widows Network' on 'Networks'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file manager, press ctrl+l to activate the address bar, and then type the address smb://youripaddress.

This assumes of course the samba share is set up correctly (likely since you can access it from Windows 10) and the smbclient package is installed (pretty sure it is by default).

Comment: Hi thanks! I opened the folder with the File Manger. Where is it located in the file system? so that I can access the directory from terminal. I mean where is the mount point?

Comment: For that you would need to mount it. Make sure cifs-utils is installed and you have a folder created for the mount point already, say for example /mnt/myshare. Take a look here for a detailed write-up...https://tecadmin.net/mounting-samba-share-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks, I found it under /run/user/"myuserid(1000)"/gvfs so I could make a symbolic link using it.

Comment: Just depends on what you need. The advantage of following the link and using cifs-utils is you can add it to fstab to auto mount on boot. It will also be faster than using gvfs.